# How do I update table field sequentially as row count

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for an idea that I want to update my table column like: when count first 5 rows then column='class' and next row would be 'Exam' And then again after this 6 rows it will same for 5 and next 1 until get last.

```
Sample data:
2016-01-18  Class
2016-01-19  Class
2016-01-20  Class
2016-01-21  Class
2016-01-23  Class
2016-01-24  Exam
2016-01-25  Class
2016-01-26  Class
2016-01-27  Class
2016-01-28  Class
2016-01-30  Class
2016-01-31  Exam
2016-02-01  Class
2016-02-02  Class
2016-02-03  Class
2016-02-04  Class
2016-02-06  Class
2016-02-07  Exam
```

Comment: I for one am having trouble understanding tour question.  Read through [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Post some sample data and expected results and what you have tried and I'm sure we can help!

Comment: @xQbert, I added the sample data that I want like, please take a look.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to update a table of of two columns and set  the `class` column to 'class' in rows 1-5, 7-11, 13-17 etc..
 In row 6, 12, 18 etc... you want to set it to 'Exam' when you order by the `date` column  So if your order by date, and generate a row number all you would have to do is check to see if the remainder when you divide by 6 is 0 and that `class` column would read exam, the rest would be class.

Comment: I want to update table one column only, order by date 1-5= class and 6=Exam and then from row#7 will start 1-5=class and 6=Exam like so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
UPDATE test t
INNER JOIN (SELECT sdate, @row :=@row +1 AS row,mod(@row,6) AS num
        FROM test, (SELECT @row := 0) r) AS tt
    ON t.sdate = tt.sdate
  SET t.name =
        CASE num 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Exam'
            ELSE 'Class'
        END;
```

If there are additional field `day_off` and we need to imply this update only for fields where day_off='':

```
UPDATE test2 t
INNER JOIN (SELECT sdate, @row :=@row +1 AS row,mod(@row,6) AS num
        FROM test2, (SELECT @row := 0) r 
  WHERE day_Off = '') AS tt
    ON t.sdate = tt.sdate
  SET t.name =
        CASE num 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Exam'
            ELSE 'Class'
        END;
```

Comment: sir, how do I escape off day, I mean ` WHERE t.day_Off=' '`

Comment: I don't understand your question about WHERE t.day_Off=' '. There are no such column in your table and no description in question. Describe this field here in comment.

Comment: sir, the table contain another column named `day_Off` And filled with reason by date. Need to count row which are not filled. Is there any way that row count `where day_Off=''`. The code working perfectly but it's cover all date

Comment: I add desired query to answer - I just add WHERE day_Off = '' to subquery

Comment: it's really great sir, but honestly I never seen such type of subquery with row id. Thanks you so much.

Comment: could you please tell me what does mean `r` in subquery?

Comment: (SELECT @row := 0) is derived table and we must add alias for it. If we write subquery in this manner `SELECT sdate, @row :=@row +1 AS row,mod(@row,6) AS num FROM test2, (SELECT @row := 0) WHERE day_Off = ''` we get error `ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: Thanks again Sir, I never forget this great lesson.